# Log4j - log JUnit current test method name

Tags: junit, log4j, junit4

I have a bunch of tests (JUnit) and a lot of logging performed using log4j in various code called from those tests.

I now need to separate logs in files between tests similarly to how JUnit separates stdout and stderr. The easiest way I see is to somehow log test class&name (for example, using MDC) along with the logging messages.

I can't just direct all logging to console and rely on JUnit to assign stdout to proper test since piece of logging that I want to analyze should not be visible in standard output.

The only solution I see is to have some special @Rule that will put test class&method name into MDC, however I'd rather not change the tests themselves since it would complicate further support.

Comment: Writing an own rule that sets the test name in MDC is IMHO the best solution.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I'll have to do just that in the end. The main issue I have with that approach is, however, that every other developer in the team will now have to be informed that each test class must contain said rule.